# Jmeter is not Sending Parameter accountNumber even though that is Set on the Http Request

Tags: api, jmeter, web-api-testing

This is very strage issue that I found. I am trying to send a request from the jemeter. it keeps saying me the badrequest and accountNumber is not set. But I am setting it from the Paramters from Jemeter.
Same request I am running from the Postman and it is working but not working from the Jmeter.

[image]

[image]

Any help will be greatly appriciated

Request header

```
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik9FWUZrWVJmUU0zX2tLamEzTGJ0Q0EiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE2NTM4MDQ5OTcsImV4cCI6MTY1MzgwODU5NywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAtaW5mLWlkcy10cy1xYS5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCIsImF1ZCI6ImRvYy1nZW4iLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJkb2MtZ2VuIiwiY2xpZW50X1NoYXJlZFNlY3JldCI6ImNzZ0MwcWNWZkIvLzlJZ1NpUTE5RUdRUlYrRURwNWZ6QzIyaHRMWmdYSVU9Iiwic2NvcGUiOlsiZG9jLWdlbiJdfQ.cFtbTYmUKRa-8jlm9uLlsax-9lylOEvpdO9WxDN-eXpBlQtryLjrtaZvxGTM2kMRLwSd97jZIth0v6PnuQivEiEenvg0nYI02rfCDmNVNgvIzeplsBrD410MaeyGNYHfdWT_ZgfhWdhgosf7b-8h22Br6ySfojd8hUaTt5njgoYf7x5hBrylgE8URN_D9SUpQY7r9v1Pftwx4S6E5cKa8Uc5kt4hQdaXvJnu0WixLBcAL38HqDaIIZwP-r9dHJ_j0sSWs7baPm_9ekK4NI_BByx1wY8jzeSbnmtIEyCAkVXtVQ4SCYd7DqejZnsM0hJ62_keAoOpFzfbnwBo6BqNfg
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length: 25
Host: app-test.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.11)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the request URL and body from the view result tree from JMeter? Also if possible please let us know the request header

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick Added Request header

Comment: Can you show how you sent it in postman?

Comment: @user7294900 Added the Postman Request too Thanks

Comment: @KishanBheemajiyani accountNumber is empty in postman ..., also Host is different

Comment: @user7294900 I have kept it blank because i dont want to run server side. But it does worked with account number in postman

Comment: you can also send parameter in Path as Intialize?accountNumber=12345

Comment: @user7294900 you mean in Jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can do it by this way,

Change the `path of the http request sampler` to `/api/vi/Documents/Requests/Initialize?accountNumber=88925982303` and add a header manager with below details,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah that does work for me. But Very strnage its not taking from parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to successfully run your request using Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Import JMeter's MITM certificate to Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)
   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

In particular your case you need to pass the `accountNumber` in URL, not in the request body.

Comment: I can try this thing